# Filter array and return value if key is present or a default value

Tags: python

Is possible to filter an array for a specific key value and return value for that key?

I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        "action_type": "landing_page_view",
        "value": "72"
    },
    {
        "action_type": "link_click",
        "value": "6"
    }        
]
```

How can I get the value for `action_type: link_click` and return 0 if this action_type won't exist?

edit: I would like to avoid big loops.

Comment: Your base data type is a list, so there's no way to avoid looping.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "big loops"?

Comment: `b = [item['value'] if item['action_type'] == "link_click" else 0 for item in a]`

Comment: @roganjosh it returns me another Array and I want to have a single result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the next() function:

```
L      = [... your list .... ]
key    = "link_click"
result = next( (d["value"] for d in L if d["action_type"]==key), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, you can use the [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) built-in function.

It requires a lambda function. In this case it would be something like

```py
lambda x: x['action_type'] == "link_click"
```

And to convert the result to a list:

```py
dt = [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '72'},
      {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '6'}]

list (filter (lambda x: x['action_type'] == "link_click", dt))                            
# Returns [{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '6'}]
```

It will return an empty list if nothing is found.

Returning a 0 if nothing is found is very simple after that.

```py
# data - the input data
# key - the key to search
# val - the value to compare with
# key2 - the key whose value should be returned in case of a match
def flt (data, key, val, key2):
    found = list (filter (lambda x: x[key] == val, data))
    if found:
        return found[0][key2]
    return 0
```

And to make it even sleeker, using the `next` function as @alain-t suggested.

```py
def flt (data, key, val, key2): 
    return next (filter (lambda x: x[key] == val, data), {key2: 0})[key2]
```

Comment: This is good, but can you show how to return 0 if the action_type key doesn't exist, like OP asked?

Comment: Yes, just check if the returned list is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to achieve that:

```
def filter_function(l):
    result = [ item["value"] for item in l if item["action_type"] == "landing_page_view"]   
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result
    else:
        return 0

l = [
        {
            "action_type": "landing_page_view",
            "value": "72"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "6"
        }
    ]

print(filter_function(l))
```

Comment: Doesn't give 0 in the case that the search value doesn't match, it just drops it

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[
    {
        "action_type": "landing_page_view",
        "value": "72"
    },
    {
        "action_type": "link_click",
        "value": "6"
    }        
]

res = list(filter(lambda x: x['action_type']=='link_click',x))
sol = list(map(lambda x:x['value'], res))

if sol==[]: 
    print(0)
else:
     print(sol)



# output ['6']
```